# Android ArrayAdapter with viewholder giving different result every time

Tags: android

I have a custom ArrayAdapter for a listview. I have two types of rows with pretty much the same content except some graphical things like background and alignments.

This is what it looks like:

```
public class ChatAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MessageSource.Message> {

private Context context;
private List<MessageSource.Message> items;
private int deviceId;

public ChatAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<MessageSource.Message> items, int deviceId) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, items);
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
    this.deviceId = deviceId;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView from;
    protected TextView message;
    protected TextView time;
}

@Override
public View getView(int p, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    ViewHolder viewHolder ;
    if(convertView == null) {
        if (items.get(p).deviceId == deviceId) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_row_right, parent, false);
        } else {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_row_left, parent, false);
        }
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.from = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bubble_from);
        viewHolder.message = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bubble_message);
        viewHolder.time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bubble_time);

        viewHolder.from.setTypeface(Font.rLight(context));
        viewHolder.message.setTypeface(Font.rLight(context));
        viewHolder.time.setTypeface(Font.rLight(context));

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.from.setText(items.get(p).nickName);
    viewHolder.message.setText(items.get(p).message);
    viewHolder.time.setText(DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(items.get(p).created * 1000, System.currentTimeMillis(), 0));

    return convertView;
}
}
```

With this line I determine which of the layouts to use:

```
if (items.get(p).deviceId == deviceId) {
```

But it seems to be randomly ignored and chooses the layout as it see fits. 
Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Just keep logs and check, what values you're getting items.get(p).deviceId and check the position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking deviceId only when convertView == null. To get correct result you should also check what layout convertView offered to you contains and if it is not of correct type inflate a new one.

Fortunately listview has support for situations like yours - override getViewTypeCount and getItemViewType as follows:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType( int p ) {
    return items.get(p).deviceId == deviceId ? 0 : 1;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}
```

Then you do not have to check View type because listview handles this check for you - it caches all view types you use separately and passes correct one to your getView method.

Comment: Thanks @Okas. But I'm a little confused. Overriding the two methods as you wrote works. But you also wrote that I'm only checking when convertView == null, do you mean that I should do something similar if converView != null or do you think Overriding the two methods is enough?